# Screen turns yellow even using the live option Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics

I've already performed the tests and changed the cable. I've come to the conclusion that it's not a problem with the cables or the monitors because I tested it with other distros even in Windows and the image is normal. I believe it's a problem with Wayland with the Nvidia video card, as my GPU is a GTX Nvidia GeForce 1650 Super.

[image]

[image]

Comment: with Xorg it works properly?

Comment: I managed to solve the problem, I had to set the monitor calibration in Settings/Color and set sRGB as default for both monitors.

Comment: Thanks, that was it @AleksanderPalamar . To people who can't see correctly, there's an arrow/chevron to the right in the monitor, click that and then delete the color profile. In the new menu scroll until you see sRGB and click on that!

Comment: @AleksanderPalamar omg ty so much ... this just happened to me, so frustrating - almost went and bought a new display despite this being brand new! TY TY!

Comment: @AleksanderPalamar - thank you!  This was the fix needed!

Answer (score 14):

I fixed it.

New answer,

Reviewer said enabling wayland fixed it.

Set WaylandEnable=false to true

```
sudo nano /etc/gdm3/custom.conf

# set it to true

WaylandEnable=true
```

Then restart gdm3

```
sudo systemctl restart gdm3
```

---

Original answer

I was using nouveau, part of mesa, the default open source nvidia driver.

Somehow the windowing system switched from wayland to x11 and then I got yellow screen(1st screen) and red screed(2nd screen).

I reinstalled mesa related pkg.

```
sudo apt autoremove mesa*
sudo apt install mesa*
```

Then I

```
sudo nano /etc/gdm3/custom.conf
```

Set WaylandEnable=false to true

```
WaylandEnable=true
```

Then restart gdm3

```
sudo systemctl restart gdm3
```

I don't know when it switched to x11, but x11 doesn't seem to be working well with nouveau on ubuntu 22.

Comment: Just enabling Wayland fixed it for me

Comment: For me the same.... Just enabling Wayland fixed it!

Comment: I guess it’s a bug in the latest X then.

Comment: worked, on nvidia driver

Comment: enabling wayland breaks the program I want to actually use. It depends on Xorg. this is not a fix

Answer (score 10):

It appears this is a reality. I was fine the other day before upgrading to 22.04 and now, my secondary display (my TV) has a yellow tint like it's stuck on Night Light mode. I've tried everything I can think of and I cannot fix the issue. I have also come to the same conclusion as you

UPDATE:
It seems that the profile might be getting corrupted somehow? I removed the profile that was automatically assigned and set the RGB profile to D65 and everything seems fine again. I also tried a few others in the list and they seemed to be OK. Give it a whirl and it will likely solve your problem.

Comment: Yes, this is definitely an issue.  I have an Asus TUF A17 which uses a TU116M [GeForce GTX 1660 Ti Mobile] on the USB-C output and AMD Renoir on the HDMI output.  I have both of these outputs connected to identical Dell SR2320L monitors (via a USB-C to HDMI adapter on one).  I use the nouveau drivers, and this worked under 21.10.  After the upgrade to 22.04, the monitor connected to the Nvidia card displayed any lighter color as a shade of bright yellow.   Deleting the monitor's color profile and replacing it with "Best RGB" fixed it.

Comment: "Best RGB" didn't support Night Light in my case and seemed like it had reduces colors. "Standard Space - sRGB" did for me.

Comment: How do you delete the color profile?

Comment: Go to settings > color > select your monitor > add profile > Colorspace: sRGB.

Comment: Not working in my case. Nvidia 1050 Ti

Comment: Thanks @PrashantSaraswat- your suggestion worked like charm.

Answer (score 4):

I tried many solutions related to the driver, but then I got the roundabout method to solve the problem.
Solution:

1. Go to setting.
2. Go to color section.
3. Select a different color profile for the display you are having this issue.
4. You can try any color profile until you are satisfied.
5. Try: Bruce RGB, Best RGB, Beta RGB, colorspace: sRGB, D50, etc...

Comment: This solution works for me!!!

Comment: In my case I tried a lot of the color profiles but the results remained the same. I nudged my HDMI a bit and it fixed it. So it probably was the HDMI cable

Answer (score 1):

I am laughing because I had the same problem after upgrading to 22.10 and I spend hours trying to tune the color balance with xgamma and many others utilities packages,
But At the end it was the night light adjustment  in settings--> Dispay --> night light.
So I hope this will save precious time to others.

Answer (score 0):

Also, you can choose “Safe graphics” boot option if you just need to use live for something like cloning a hard drive.

Confirmed this fixes the yellow screen issue on Ubuntu 22.04.01 LTS.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For those who have reason to stay on Xorg and haven’t found success with the results above, I was able to fix this issue by using nvidia’s proprietary drivers instead of the open source nouveau ones. I know this isn’t the fix most people are looking for but it fixed my problems.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it very easily: I switched from Xorg to Ubuntu (during login, small gear on the right side below) :-o
Wow...

Comment: Below what? Can you provide an image to add clarity?

Comment: svo's referring to a dropdown menu.

Answer (score 0):

for me, I was missing drivers

`sudo apt install nvidia-driver-<version>`