# Fresh USB 22.04 install boots to green illegible screen

Tags: 22.04, monitor-calibration

[image]
Is there some kind of screen calibration in the default install to cause this?  Monitor is Asus Art monitor which has worked just fine with prior Ubuntu installs

initial display is correct, select 'Try Ubuntu' and you see second image[image]

Comment: the color scheme looks similar to the one [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1404516/screen-turns-yellow-even-using-the-live-option-ubuntu-22-04) . You could give his solution a try, and also try switching between wayland/x11(not sure whether this option is available in "try ubuntu" mode) and the graphic drivers too. Kindly update your findings with more system info as it'd be easier to narrow down other possible solutions.

Answer (score 0):

good link @ManOnTheMoon
from the green/yellow screen which is the desktop, I went to settings the color and managed to find the color profile which needed to be deleted and then replaced by rbg
thanks!