# Ubuntu 22.04 LTS - yellowish screen

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, screen

I tried to do in place upgrade from Ubuntu LTS 20.4 LTS to Ubuntu 22.04 LTS which failed. I did a fresh install.
I have Nvidia GE force GTX 1050 Ti graphics card. It was working all fine when I had Ubuntu LTS 20.4 LTS. But ever since I have Ubuntu 22.04 LTS - I have a yellowish screen color. What should I do? I have two regular 32 inch LG displays. Same display is working fine in my Windows 11(it's a dual boot system).
It's hard to express this via picture/images as most of the smartphone camera does some kind of white balance.

Came across this [link](https://ghitab.net/2022/05/06/ubuntu-22-04-yellow-screen-after-first-restart-nvidia-driver/)

But I already have
[image]

[Existing Bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1969959)

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what worked for me

Go to settings > color > select your monitor > add profile > Colorspace: sRGB.

Answer provided by Prashant in this [thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1404516/screen-turns-yellow-even-using-the-live-option-ubuntu-22-04)

Answer (score 0):

I found the above response a touch confusing initially as I couldn’t find the ‘Color’ option. However, I noted a number of similar explanations so thought there is clearly something to the advice.

However, what I was able to workout is that you have to do go into > Settings > Device Colour Profiles. Where my screen details was displayed in the pop up window I first removed that specific profile and then I added a profile. By doing that I was able to select > Colourspace: sRGB and that did the trick.